# What is the best JSS template field naming convention

Tags: jss, templates

What is the best practice for naming the template fields in Sitecore JSS?

Layout service is not making any changes to the filed names when returning JSON response so it seems quite natural to use camelCase for that although it is in contradiction to PascalCase I saw in all the projects I used to work on so far.

Which convention are you using on your project and why? Are there any implications making one of them a better choice or this is just a preference?

Comment: Check this one - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25358/jss-field-naming-convention, this may help you

Comment: @GauravAgarwal thanks, I saw this post but it does not answer fully my question hence I created a new one :)

Comment: Your field names are for humans to work with, not for code. You should neither focus on Pascal Case or camelCase, your field names should be natural.

Comment: This is why we have the display name which can be set separately, my question was if there is any difference from the code perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vanilla JavaScript, the convention is to use camelCase for field names, and PascalCase for class names.

In React, the convention is to use PascalCase only for component names.

So to answer your question, I'd recommend camelCase for the actual field names, and utilizing display names for the Content Author's readability sake.